# Broken Packages and Ubuntu upgrade Issue from 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 20.10

Previously I upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10

For upgrading ubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04 I did this

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Following error occurred

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.
```

By executing this command

```
 grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
```

I got a list of Broken packages.

```
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on libwbclient0:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 -> 2:4.13.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umU > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken sssd:amd64 Depends on sssd-ad:amd64 < 2.3.1-3ubuntu4 @ii umH Ib > (= 2.4.0-1ubuntu6)
Broken libtss2-mu0:amd64 Breaks on libtss2-esys0:amd64 < 3.0.1-1 @ii mK > (< 3.0.1-2)
Broken vim:amd64 Depends on vim-common:amd64 < 2:8.2.0716-3ubuntu2 -> 2:8.2.2434-1ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 2:8.2.0716-3ubuntu2)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on hplip-data:amd64 < 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1 -> 3.21.2+dfsg1-2 @ii umU > (= 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libhpmud0:amd64 < 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1 -> 3.21.2+dfsg1-2 @ii umU > (= 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libsane-hpaio:amd64 < 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1 -> 3.21.2+dfsg1-2 @ii umU IPb > (= 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on printer-driver-hpcups:amd64 < 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1 -> 3.21.2+dfsg1-2 @ii umU > (= 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.6-0ubuntu1 -> 3.9.4-1 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken libsrt1.4-gnutls:amd64 Breaks on libsrt1-gnutls:amd64 < 1.4.1-5build1 @ii mK >
Broken sssd-ad:amd64 Depends on libsss-idmap0:amd64 < 2.3.1-3ubuntu4 -> 2.4.0-1ubuntu6 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-3ubuntu4)
Broken sssd-ipa:amd64 Depends on libipa-hbac0:amd64 < 2.3.1-3ubuntu4 -> 2.4.0-1ubuntu6 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-3ubuntu4)
Broken sssd-ipa:amd64 Depends on libsss-idmap0:amd64 < 2.3.1-3ubuntu4 -> 2.4.0-1ubuntu6 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-3ubuntu4)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 -> 2.3.1-2ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 -> 2:2.2.0-3ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1)
Broken python3-dev:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.6-0ubuntu1 -> 3.9.4-1 @ii umU > (= 3.8.6-0ubuntu1)
Broken sssd-ad-common:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii umH Ib > (>= 2:4.13.3+dfsg)
Broken libomp5-12:amd64 Conflicts on libomp-x.y:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 @ii umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 -> 2.3.1-2ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 -> 2:2.2.0-3ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 @ii umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 -> 2.3.1-2ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 -> 2:2.2.0-3ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii umR > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii umR > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 @ii umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii umR > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken gvfs-backends:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.12.0+dfsg)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.38.3-0ubuntu1 | 1:3.38.5-1ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.38.3-0ubuntu1 | 1:3.38.5-1ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii ugR > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on hplip-data:amd64 < 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1 -> 3.21.2+dfsg1-2 @ii ugU > (= 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libhpmud0:amd64 < 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1 -> 3.21.2+dfsg1-2 @ii ugU > (= 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libsane-hpaio:amd64 < 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1 -> 3.21.2+dfsg1-2 @ii ugU IPb > (= 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on printer-driver-hpcups:amd64 < 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1 -> 3.21.2+dfsg1-2 @ii ugU > (= 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.6-0ubuntu1 -> 3.9.4-1 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii ugR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii ugR > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii ugR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii ugR > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii ugR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 @ii ugR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 -> 2.3.1-2ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 -> 2:2.2.0-3ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii ugR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii ugR > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii ugR > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii ugR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 @ii ugR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 -> 2.3.1-2ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-1)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.6-0ubuntu1 -> 3.9.4-1 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 -> 2:2.2.0-3ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.6-0ubuntu1 -> 3.9.4-1 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii ugR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii ugR > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.38.3-0ubuntu1 | 1:3.38.5-1ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.38.3-0ubuntu1 | 1:3.38.5-1ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.459 | 1.469 @ii umR >
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii ugR > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii ugR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 @ii ugR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 -> 2.3.1-2ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-1)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.6-0ubuntu1 -> 3.9.4-1 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 -> 2:2.2.0-3ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-1 -> 2.3.1-2ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 -> 2:2.2.0-3ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.1.4-2ubuntu0.1 @ii ugR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii ugR > (= 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.12.5+dfsg-3ubuntu4.4 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.38.3-0ubuntu1 | 1:3.38.5-1ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.38.3-0ubuntu1 | 1:3.38.5-1ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.459 | 1.469 @ii umR >
```

why did this happen?" && How to remove or fix all broken packages at once ??

Comment: A better question would be "*why did this happen?*" so you can prevent it from happening again. The term *broken* does NOT mean that the packages are defective or corrupt. It means that the packages are *incompatble* with something else that you have already installed. Some non-Ubuntu or wrong-version package that you installed is blocking completion of your release-upgrade. Uninstall THAT package (which is not on the list) to fix the problem.

Comment: how to find THAT package as there are tons of package installed? what keyword to focus on to find THAT package from
  `apt list --installed `

Comment: Edit your question. Comments are intended to help you improve until it is answerable. Comments are not intended for conversation.

Comment: Do you have apps installed from a PPA? There is a chance that the conflicts come from the unexpected dependencies generated from installing apps from PPA. If some of these apps are available in Ubuntu repos, you can try to install from those repos and disable the related PPA.

Comment: I have cleared all PPA dependencies from `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d ` 
Is there any path where PPAs are stored ?? And What else can cause this Broken Package other than PPAs? Any was to fix this?

Comment: You can't just remove the ppas. You have to remove the different versions of the programs installed from those ppas, and replace them with the versions from the Ubuntu repos. The program `ppa-purge` can help you with this.

Comment: How to find which programs are installed from different versions of PPAs and how to remove them?

Comment: I suggest reinstall from fresh.

Comment: Since you removed the ppas from the sources list, you have to put them back, then use `ppa-purge`.

Comment: How can I get back all deleted PPAs from the source list??

Comment: Did you keep notes about what changes you made? You may be able to recover some information by using the `history` command, depending on how exactly you did things.

Comment: I don't have the list of packages that  I removed from /etc/apt/sources.list.d. Is there any other way to fix the broken packages and upgrade to 21.04?